# jQuery validation: allowing form submission in spite of errors

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I am running into issues with the [jquery form validation](http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/) plugin. It is allowing the form to be submitted in IE, also, it is allowing form submission in Firefox if two previously invalid required fields are fixed (even if there are other invalid fields).

http://superuntitled.com/dev/index.html

The js is the most basic use of `validate()`

```
$("#emailform").validate();
```

The class names are correctly set (`required`, `email`).

Are there any none gotchas or bugs for this script?

I am using jQuery 1.6.2 and the jQuery Validation Plugin 1.8.1

Comment: I ran into the same problem. Scripts that worked fine all of a sudden just started allowing forms to be submitted with errors. No matter if I was using the long form of validate or just the basic like you are. Also I started getting errors in firebug like jquery.format() was not valid. My forms were submitted through ajax with errors

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may be triggering JavaScript exceptions, which are causing your script to terminate. Once that happens, the default form is submitted, as that would be the normal HTML action without the JS.